# What happens to the data that will be returned when thread is waiting for other threads

Tags: multithreading

Let's say I create many many threads on one core CPU. Each thread does IO operation, for example it reads data from a database or other microservice.
What happens if I create thousands of threads that read something from a DB?

How this communication works?

I assume that in a thread we send some request to a DB or some HTTP call to other service. After that CPU is used by another thread. How is this communcation handled? Does the OS handle messages for other threads and waits until these threads will be used by CPU to pass them data?

Lets say I make 1000 calls in 1000 of threads and each response will be 1MB of data. Where is this data buffored until correct thread become active? (For example we are spawning tenth thread and already got a response fot the first one)

Or maybe someone could pass some nice articles about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a thread makes an I/O request the OS (kernel) queues that I/O and puts the thread to sleep (assuming we're talking about a synchronous I/O call).

"Queues that I/O" means setting up some link between the socket through which the I/O is performed and the network card queue, and setting up an internal OS buffer to hold request and response data.

When a response arrives at the network card, the OS adds the data socket's buffer and, typically, wakes up the thread that made the associated I/O request.

Note that while an HTTP or DB query response can be 1 MB, it's usually done over a TCP/IP connection, which usually has a much lower [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit). The TCP/IP implementation will require the server to slice the response into packets and send multiple small packets.

If 1000 responses arrive at the same time, and the hardware cannot handle such a load, each server will have to send its packets more slowly, but the OS will still likely handle all such "streams" of responses in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer. Could you also add what could be a bottleneck here? What if I use a web server and receive a huge number of requests? What will fail first?

Comment: That is way too environment dependent. In some setups you'll run out of network bandwidth, in some you'll exhaust your memory first. There are also OS limits on the number of threads, not to mention that the web server implementation would typically not be implemented using synchronous I/O.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that in a thread we send some request to a DB or some HTTP call to other service. After that CPU is used by another thread. How is this communcation handled? Does the OS handle messages for other threads and waits until these threads will be used by CPU to pass them data?

It depends on the exact communication method used. Most commonly, it will be some kind of byte stream connection such as a TCP connection. In that case, the thread typically makes a blocking read operation that causes the kernel to mark that thread as waiting for I/O. It attaches the thread to a data structure associated with the TCP connection and does whatever is needed to make that I/O take effect.

When a response is received, the kernel code notices the thread waiting for activity. It then marks that original thread ready-to-run and the scheduler will eventually schedule it. When it runs, it resumes in the kernel's blocking I/O code, but this time there is data waiting for it, so it returns to user space and resumes execution.

> Lets say I make 1000 calls in 1000 of threads and each response will be 1MB of data. Where is this data buffored until correct thread become active? (For example we are spawning tenth thread and already got a response fot the first one)

It depends on exactly what communication method is used. If it's a TCP connection, then there are buffers associated with that connection. If it uses shared memory, then the other process just writes into that shared memory page.

Comment: thanks, where do you have that knowledge from? Where could I read about that? Any book, course?

Comment: @Mateusz I've learned it from working on code in every piece of that chain over decades. There must be an easier way, but I don't know what it is. ;)